# fixing text to the footer

Tags: html, css

as you see in the picture the links of the right side aren't properly fixed to my footer
what should I do to make it correct?
I don't know why between these two parts I mean div links I have a big distance
I don't want this distance between them either.

I inserted the style and my tables in the footer.
Thanks in advance

[image]
**style if needed:**

```
    <style>
#footer{
    background-image:url(../images/footer.png);
    background-position:inherit;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    margin:0
    auto;
    text-align: right;
    }
    #links ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            width: 400px;
            float:right;
                text-align: right;
    } 

    #links li {
            border: 1px dotted #999;
            border-width: 2px 0;
            margin: 5px 0;
            float:right;
                text-align: right;
    }

    #links li a { 
            color: #FF6600;
            display: block;
            font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding: 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            float:right;
            text-align: right;

    }

     * html #links li a {  /* make hover effect work in IE */
        width:600px;
        float:right;
            text-align: right;
    }

    #links li a:hover {
            background: #FFFFFF ;
    }

    #links a em { 
            color: #333;
            display: block;
            font: normal 85% Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            line-height: 125%;
            float:right; 
            text-align: right;
    }

    #links a span {
            color: #125F15;
            font: normal 70% Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            line-height: 150%;
            float:right;
    }
    </style>
```

**the footer and the texts:**

```
   <div id="footer">
<table width="100%" height="183" align="left" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr">
<tr>
<td width="30%">
 <div id="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="لینک">سرویس های مشتری
       <table width="100%">
        <tr>
        <td width="337" cellpadding="0"><em>ارتباط با ما</em></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td> <em>ثبت نام</em></td></tr>
        <tr><td> <em>پرسش و پاسخ</em></td></tr>
        </table>
        </a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div> 

  </td>
 <td width="40%">
 <div id="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="لینک">لینک های مفید
        <table width="100%">
        <tr><td width="337">
        <em>لینک یک</em></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
         <em>لینک دو</em>
         </td></tr>
          <tr><td>
         <em>لینک سه</em>
         </td></tr>
         </table>
        </a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div> 
  </td>
   <td width="30%">
 <div id="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="لینک">اخبار
        <table width="100%">
        <tr><td width="337">
        <em>خبر یک</em></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
         <em>خبر دو</em>
         </td></tr>
          <tr><td>
         <em>خبر سه</em>
         </td></tr>
         </table>
        </a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not found issue with your code or styles. The issue may be related to the backgrounds. Please provide the live site link for checking.

Comment: your table width is exceeding, what is the width of #footer?

Comment: try making the table width set to 100% & td width to 50%. The problem is because of table i am sure. It will work fine if you use div & unordered list for this.

Comment: sorry you mean which table? this one <div id="footer">
<table width="100%" height="183" cellpadding="0">?

Comment: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/aQ2zW/

Comment: you solved my problem yes I inserted 50% and now works fine please answer then I can check you as best answer

Comment: @SVS now I inseted another part I mean another div to test it it doesn't work with 3 parts why? I made the percenteges to 30%-40%-30%

Comment: Can you post your complete #footer code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14389/discussion-between-svs-and-negin-nicki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, make the width of table inside `#footer` 100%. & accordingly divide the width of `<td>` in percentage.

Actually padding to `#footer` is pushing the last table row outside, because padding increase the width of `#footer` so make the width of `#footer` to `960px` as applied padding is 20px on left & right.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you really shouldn't be using tables for layout it is not semantically correct, tables should only be used for tabular data.  Secondly you can surround a table with a a tag  which isn't valid.

I suspect that your issue are around poor use of tables

```
<div id="footer">
  <ul class="left">
    <li> <a href="link">links here...</a><li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
     <li> <a href="link">links here...</a><li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

then css like this:

```
#footer{
  width:100%;
  /* other style here... */
}

.left{
  float:left;
  margin:5px 10px;
}

.right{
  float:right;
  margin:5px 10px;
}
```

This should make your footer sit is the position you want and be more semantically correct

Comment: Thanks if I wanted to have for example more than two parts I mean three parts I need to define another class middle but for the float what should I set now?

Comment: Tableception, tables within tables within aaahhmmggg. +1 for proper semantics.

Comment: @Marrowmaw ok I cleared all the tables and now I have a mess footer what should I do with it?

Comment: just add another ul with left class and it should sit fine :)